# Paragraph shows as child of another element even after RichTextbox clear

Tags: c#, silverlight, richtextbox, silverlight-5.0, paragraph

I have two RichTextboxes on my page. I am using them as a Book interface. There are two buttons to turn forward and back.

Traversing through the pages forward works fine. But once I hit back, VS2010 shoots an exception

```
Element is already the child of another element.
```

This is for the paragraph I am adding in the RichTextbox. This happen even though I am clearing both the RichTextboxes before flooding them with new data.

My code below. What am I missing?

```
TxtBlobLeft.Blocks.Clear();
        TxtBlobRight.Blocks.Clear();


        foreach (Paragraph item in pagesStack[count].paras)
        {
            TxtBlobLeft.Blocks.Add(item); //Throws exception here
        }


        foreach (Paragraph item in pagesStack[count + 1].paras)
        {
            TxtBlobRight.Blocks.Add(item);
        }
```

Note: pagesStack is a custom Object with Paras (i.e List) as a property.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the RichTextbox control, so I'm not sure about some of your properties here. Is there a custom object you need to more fully explain? I'm guessing TxtBlobLeft is a RichTextbox, but I'm not finding the Blocks property or understanding how you are adding the item of type Paragraph. Despite all that, it seems that you have a reference in the paragraph object to the rich text box that needs to be removed before you go back and add it again.

Comment: Yes. TxtBlobLeft is the RichTextbox. And yes, apparently TxtBlobLeft.Blocks.Clear() does not remove the element.

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue. I think it's a bug in RTB.

Comment: My workaround was to recreate the Paragraph each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Clear doesn't remove the parent reference of Paragraphs to the RTB. I created a new method for Clear using the following forach loop to remove all items.

```
foreach (Paragraph item in paras)
        {
            Page1.Blocks.Remove(item);
        }
```

paras is my List of Paragraphs which I had added to the RTB previously.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in debugger what is the Parent of item when you enter loop?

Comment: The parent is the RichTextbox itself. It does not get removed when I clear the elements.